# ansible_facts.packages "skipping" my package check

Tags: ansible, package, ansible-facts

I would like to check if my package is installed, but I would like to have all package types with a name.

Let me explain: I am looking for the OB2 package, but there are plenty of them, so I am looking for `OB2*` but it skips my search.

I tested with the name without wildcard (`*`) but it doesn't work any better:

```yaml
- name: Gather the package facts
  ansible.builtin.package_facts:
    manager: auto

- name: Print the package facts
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: ansible_facts.packages
    
- name: Check whether a package called OB2 is installed
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['OB2*'] | length }} versions of OB2are installed!"
  when: "'OB2*' in ansible_facts.packages"
```

Is there a solution to find all outputs that start with `OB2` within `ansible_facts.package`?

Answer (score 3):

[`ansible_facts.packages` is a dictionary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html#return-ansible_facts/packages). There are no keys in that dictionary named `OB2*` nor `OB2` since no package has this exact name.

If you want to get all keys which names start with the string `"OB2"`, one way is to filter out all others.

- Transform you dict to a key/value list with the [`dict2items` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists)
- Use the [`selectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) and apply the [`match` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) to find the relevant entries.
- Since the `key` name is also contained in the parameter `name` inside each element in the `value` list , you can retain only the `value` using the [`map(attribute='someattr')` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map)
- Last, [flatten the list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) to get one single list containing all packages version

Here is a playbook illustrating the concept. For the example, I used as a prefix `"zlib"`. Just change it back to whatever suits your needs

```yaml
 ---
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false
 
   vars:
     package_prefix: "zlib"
 
     filtered_packages: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | dict2items 
       | selectattr('key', 'match', package_prefix) 
       | map(attribute='value') | flatten }}"
 
   tasks:
     - name: gather package facts
       ansible.builtin.package_facts:
 
     - name: debug the raw variable
       debug:
         var: filtered_packages
 
     - name: count relevant packages
       vars:
         pkg_num: "{{ filtered_packages | count }}"
       debug:
         msg: "There are {{ pkg_num }} packages
           which name starts with {{ package_prefix }}"
 
     - name: show some info about relevant packages
       debug:
         msg: "Package named {{ item.name }} is in category {{ item.category }}
           and has version {{ item.version }}"
       loop: "{{ filtered_packages }}"
```

Which gives on my Ubuntu local machine:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************

TASK [gather package facts] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug the raw variable] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "filtered_packages": [
        {
            "arch": "amd64",
            "category": "libs",
            "name": "zlib1g",
            "origin": "Ubuntu",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3"
        },
        {
            "arch": "amd64",
            "category": "libdevel",
            "name": "zlib1g-dev",
            "origin": "Ubuntu",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [count relevant packages] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "There are 2 packages which name starts with zlib"
}

TASK [show some info about relevant packages] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'zlib1g', 'version': '1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3', 'arch': 'amd64', 'category': 'libs', 'origin': 'Ubuntu', 'source': 'apt'}) => {
    "msg": "Package named zlib1g is in category libs and has version 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'zlib1g-dev', 'version': '1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3', 'arch': 'amd64', 'category': 'libdevel', 'origin': 'Ubuntu', 'source': 'apt'}) => {
    "msg": "Package named zlib1g-dev is in category libdevel and has version 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to filter the keys, a direct address is not possible, because you don't know the exact name.

```yaml
- name: Gather the package facts
  ansible.builtin.package_facts:

- name: Filter package names
  set_fact:
    filtered_package_names: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | list 
      | map('regex_search', '^vim.*') | select('string') | list }}"
  
- name: Print filtered packages
  debug:
    var: filtered_package_names

- name: Print package details from all filtered packages
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item] }}"
  with_items: "{{ filtered_package_names }}"
```

With `list` a list of the keys is created, then you can filter this list with [`regex_search`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions), afterwards the list is reduced to the filter result.

== Edit begin

There is a smarter filter method. Instead of using `map(regex_search) / select(string)`, you could use directly `select(match)`, so the filtering would look like:

```yaml
- name: Filter package names
  set_fact:
    filtered_package_names: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | list 
      | select('match', '^vim.*') | list }}"
```

== Edit end

The result is a list of package names that match your regex.

If you need more information about one of the packages, you can then use `ansible_facts.packages[_your_item]` to get the rest of the information.

Example output of the above tasks:

```
TASK [Gather the package facts] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Filter package names] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print filtered packages] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "filtered_package_names": [
        "vim",
        "vim-common",
        "vim-runtime",
        "vim-tiny"
    ]
}

TASK [Print package details] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=vim) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "arch": "amd64",
            "category": "editors",
            "name": "vim",
            "origin": "Ubuntu",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=vim-common) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "arch": "all",
            "category": "editors",
            "name": "vim-common",
            "origin": "Ubuntu",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=vim-runtime) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "arch": "all",
            "category": "editors",
            "name": "vim-runtime",
            "origin": "Ubuntu",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=vim-tiny) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "arch": "amd64",
            "category": "editors",
            "name": "vim-tiny",
            "origin": "Ubuntu",
            "source": "apt",
            "version": "2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.7"
        }
    ]
}
```